# Number of characters in a string (escape sequences)

Tags: python

I wrote this piece of code to count the number of characters in the string `a\nb\x1f\000d`

```
#CLASS TASK-VI
ctr=0
str1="a\nb\x1f\000d"
for i in range(len(str1)):
    ctr=ctr+1
print("Number of characters in the string str1 is: ",ctr)
```

It returns `Number of characters in the string str1 is:  6`
Can someone explain this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `['a', '\n', 'b', '\x1f', '\x00', 'd']`. Besides, when you do `len(str1)`, why do you need `ctr += 1`?

Answer (score 3):

There are 6 characters in the string:

1. `a`
2. `\n`, which resolves to the single 'newline' character (also referred to as 'line feed')
3. `b`
4. `\x1f`, which is a hex escape sequence. `\x` means that the following two characters (in hexidecimal) will make up a number (in this case, `1f` -> `31`), and to use the character whose code is that number. Character number 31 happens to be an ASCII control character, known as 'unit separator'.
5. `\000` is an octal escape sequence, which is the same as above but in base 8. In this case, the code it refers to is `0`, which is the null character
6. `d`

Backslashes are a special control character that 'escape' the following character. Certain 'escape sequences' have special effects - here you see `\n`, `\x`, and `\0`, for example, though there are plenty more if you feel like looking them up. In python, you can make a string *not process escape sequences* by declaring it as a "raw string", which you do by starting the string with `r"` instead of just `"`:

```
>>> len("a\nb\x1f\000d")
6
>>> len(r"a\nb\x1f\000d")
13
```

You can also use a double-backslash `\\` to escape a backslash, thus preventing *it* from escaping something else.

```
>>> len("a\\nb\\x1f\\000d")
13
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the backslashes to be counted as characters, make them double backslashes, otherwise they represent escape characters.

```
>>> str1 = "a\\nb\\x1f\\000d"
>>> len(str1)
13
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str1= "a\nb\x1f\000d"
print(f"Number of characters in the string str1 is {len(str1)}")
# 6


str1= r"a\nb\x1f\000d"
print(f"Number of characters in the string str1 is {len(str1)}")
#13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you source the string out of python then each character will be treated as a string.
For example, make a file named *"content.txt"*. Inside that file type/paste any string you want with any special character, read it with python then it will be treated as a string.
i.e.

```
with open("content.txt") as fl:
    content = fl.read()
    print(len(content))
    print(content)
```